# Error occur in Citrus Payment Integration

Tags: java, android, citrus-pay

I just want to use citrus payment integration and when i just click on buy now button than its getting error and my app has been crash and mainly the error comes in CheckUserLogin and checkuserlogin method. I don't understand how to resolve this problem?

Error

```
        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.citrus.sdk.network.e.d()' on a null object reference
      at com.citrus.sdk.e.d(Unknown Source)
          at com.citrus.sdk.CitrusClient.signOut(Unknown Source)
        at com.citrus.sdk.CitrusClient$15.error(Unknown Source)
       at com.citrus.sdk.e.a(Unknown Source)
     at com.citrus.sdk.e.a(Unknown Source)
    at com.citrus.sdk.e$1.error(Unknown Source)
       at com.citrus.sdk.e.a(Unknown Source)
at com.citrus.sdk.e.a(Unknown Source)
 at com.citrus.sdk.e.b(Unknown Source)
  at com.citrus.sdk.CitrusClient.getPrepaidToken(Unknown Source)
  at com.citrus.sdk.CitrusClient.isUserSignedIn(Unknown Source)
  at com.codeexpertise.eshop.startup.PayPalCheckoutActivity.checkUserLogin(PayPalCheckoutActivity.java:85)
at com.codeexpertise.eshop.startup.PayPalCheckoutActivity.onResume(PayPalCheckoutActivity.java:81)
```

PayPal Checkout Activity. java (This is the java file where the checkuserlogin method is declared and in the error its show the error in checkuserlogin)

```
public class PayPalCheckoutActivity extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextView textMessage = null;
    private CitrusClient citrusClient = null;
    private Button btnSignout = null;
    private Button btnUserManagement = null;
    private Button btnWalletPayment = null;
    public boolean isUserLoggedIn = false;

    public PayPalCheckoutActivity() {
    }

    public static PayPalCheckoutActivity newInstance() {
        return new PayPalCheckoutActivity();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ui, container, false);
        textMessage = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.txt_message);

        btnUserManagement = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_user_management);
        btnWalletPayment = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_user_wallet);
        btnSignout = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
        btnSignout.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        citrusClient = CitrusClient.getInstance(getActivity());

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        citrusClient.signOut(new Callback<CitrusResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void success(CitrusResponse citrusResponse) {
                ((UIActivity) getActivity()).showSnackBar(citrusResponse.getMessage());

                textMessage.setText("Please Sign In or Sign Up the user.");
                btnSignout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                btnUserManagement.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                btnWalletPayment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

            @Override
            public void error(CitrusError error) {
                ((UIActivity) getActivity()).showSnackBar(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        checkUserLogin();
    }

    void checkUserLogin() {
        citrusClient.isUserSignedIn(new Callback<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public void success(Boolean isUserLoggedIn) {
                PayPalCheckoutActivity.this.isUserLoggedIn = isUserLoggedIn;
                if (isUserLoggedIn) {
                    citrusClient.getProfileInfo(new Callback<CitrusUser>() {
                        @Override
                        public void success(CitrusUser citrusUser) {
                            textMessage.setText("Welcome " + citrusUser.getEmailId());
                            btnWalletPayment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btnUserManagement.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnSignout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void error(CitrusError error) {
                            textMessage.setText("Welcome Back");
                            btnWalletPayment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            btnUserManagement.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            btnSignout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    textMessage.setText("Please Sign In or Sign Up the user.");
                    btnWalletPayment.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    btnUserManagement.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    btnSignout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void error(CitrusError error) {
                textMessage.setText(error.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure getActivity() is not null at line citrusClient = CitrusClient.getInstance(getActivity());

Comment: Or try to call checkUserLogin() in onCreate() or onActivityCreated()

Comment: @VVB not working still coming same error.

Comment: Did you check condition? if (citrusClient != null && getActivity() != null)

Comment: @VVB only in the paypalcheckoutactivity.java here its a private CitrusClient citrusClient = null;

Comment: There is the point, you need to get it not null in fragment as well

Comment: but i remove the null but still its showing error